# AKSequencer.init() in Audiokit 4.9

Tags: audiokit

How do I implement the AKSequencer.init in version 4.9
AKSequencer.init() does not compile any more, nor .newTrack() is available.

Answer (score 2):

AKSequencer was renamed AKAppleSequencer so just change the types and initializer to reflect the name change. AKSequencer is our own new sequencer that does not rely on any of Apple's sequencing tools.

Comment: How do we do the same thing using AKSequencer? There are no docs available for this, and it doesn't work according to what you would expect.

Comment: There are docs for the new sequencer here: https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSequencer.html